# Does it make sence using final keyword whenever it possible?

Tags: dart

А piece of code where in my opinion the `final` keyword is redundantly, is not it?
Are there any real advantages of using `final` in cases like this?

```
@action
  void markAllAsCompleted() {
    for (final todo in todos) {
      todo.done = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No semantic advantage. People differ on the readability advantage.

Some people think it's an advantage that you can see that a variable won't ever change.
It's being explicit about something which would otherwise be implicit in the code.

Others think that it's unnecessary detail and verbosity that doesn't pay for itself. Sometimes adding more information, if that information isn't really needed, is just adding more noise.

It's effectively a trade-off between explicitness and verbosity which is likely to tip in different direction for different uses. For example, a larger scope for the variable might  make it more impactful to declare the variable as final up-front, because it cues you to the variable not changing before reading a lengthy method. In a short method, like this one, you can see immediately that there are no assignments to `todo`, and reading `final` up front just slows you down ... unless you are so used to reading `final` everywhere that it doesn't really rise to the level of conscious thought.

It's individual.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you *cannot omit* the keyword, it's in no way redundant.

```
void markAllAsCompleted() {
  for (final todo in todos) {
    todo.done = true;
  }
}
```

The alternative would be

```
void markAllAsCompleted() {
  for (var todo in todos) {
    todo.done = true;
  }
}
```

So there is nothing redundant here. It's a *choice*, you can either use `var` or `final` or the datatype. Of those, only the datatype would be really redundant. So of the choice between `final` or `var` I see no reason to use the one that applies to your situation.

So if it *can* be `final`, why not make it final.